# Why do I get "Failed to set locale, defaulting to C" when using yum?

Tags: yum

Every time I run `yum install` or `yum update`, I get

> Failed to set locale, defaulting to C

and then other information.

How can I avoid getting this warning?

Answer (score 23):

I put the following locale relating setting in `/etc/bashrc` (for all users, `bash`):

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_COLLATE=C
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
```

then run:

```
source /etc/bashrc
```

or log off and log on.

Comment: This should probably go into `/etc/profile.d/lang.sh` and not to `/etc/bashrc` which is likely to be overwritten by an update.

Comment: @ccpizza I put those lines at the bottom of `lang.sh` and it worked .

Answer (score 7):

Run

`yum reinstall glibc-common`

and then make sure that no process is deleting the /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive.* files.

Comment: I tried this first and it helps for me (not checked the process)

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Comment: In newer Red Hat-based Linux distributions (Fedora 24+, RHEL 8+) this will be `glibc-langpack-<language>`, e.g. `glibc-langpack-en`.

Comment: In the Centos Docker image there's a reported bug: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1392855

Answer (score 5):

I was getting same error on MacOS. When you ssh to a linux box, they refuse to setup an `UTF-8` locale. You can see the differences in locale setting by running `locale` command on your MacOS terminal and Linux box.

To fix this error open **terminal -> preferences -> profiles -> Advanced** and unset `Set locale environment variables on startup` on your mac.

Now when you run `locale` on mac. you can see that this change has set `LC_CTYPE="C"` which was `LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"` with previous setting.

you will have to close your terminal to take this effect and now login to your linux box and run `yum update`.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 5):

If you used SSH to connect to this host from a desktop machine, it's common for `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to contain

```
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
```

which allows clients to propagate the values of those environment variables into new sessions.  However, this will cause the locale variables to be set back to empty within your SSH session on the server you are configuring, **if the locale isn't first correctly set *ON YOUR DESKTOP MACHINE***.

To Fix:

For example, in the Windows 10 Ubuntu Shell window, first do (**NOTE: change all entries below to match your locale if it's not "en_US.UTF-8"**):

```
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Then close Ubuntu shell window and re-open, and then SSH into the server you are trying to configure and see if everything is now fine...

If not, then SSH into your server and do:

```
vi /etc/profile.d/custom.lang.sh
```

Then hit `I` to enter "insert" mode. Then paste the below entries. Then `ZZ` to save and exit:

```
## US English ##
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
```

Then execute the following:

```
source /etc/profile.d/lang.sh
source /etc/profile.d/custom.lang.sh
```

Then:

```
reboot
```

See if that makes everything stop complaining about locale vars!

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
export LANG=en_US
```

Or set it to something similar. If that resolves the issue for you, you can make it persistent by modifying the bash profile.

Comment: That didn't work for me.  Any other suggestions